# Add objects in a list using java 8

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8

I am new to Java 8, so I have a list of `CollegeGroup` and I have a `Student` that has many groups. Each group has a `CollegeGroupMember` who is linked to the student. Is there any way to return these groups right in my list(studentCollegeGroups)?

```
final List<CollegeGroup> studentCollegeGroups = new ArrayList<>();
student.getCollegeGroupMembers().forEach(collegeGroupMember -> 
             studentCollegeGroups.add(collegeGroupMember.getCollegeGroup()));
```

Comment: whats wrong with your code?

Comment: Use `map(CollegeGroupMember::getCollegeGroup).forEach(studentCollegeGroups::add)` or `map(...).collect(Collectors.toList())` to collect the groups in a list which is returned to you. Bonus: After mapping to CollegeGroup you could use distinct() or sorted() intermediate operations that can operate on groups instead of members.

Comment: Thanks! I need distinct() also, thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java 8 best practice is not to add things to an outside list, but to create the whole list as the result of one stream expression.  Here, it'd probably be

```
return student.getCollegeGroupMembers().stream()
    .map(CollegeGroupMember::getCollegeGroup)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```